# What's the use of Pull Request? And how to use Bitbucket properly?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've used BitBucket before but only solo for my own personal projects. I know the basics (the very basic I must say), but for solo developer only. And even then, I did it via Source Tree, not the console. So it's a lot easier for me. My usual workflow is like this: **code->commit->code->commit->tag->push(if a feature is done)->code->commit->code->commit->...>tag>push->...** Because I'm the only one developing the project, this is fine. But now, I happen to be assigned to create and set a repo in BitBucket for collaboration in the office between me and 2 junior programmers. And honestly, I'm so confused as to how to use BitBucket with other developers besides myself.

So my questions are:

1. What is the proper way to use BitBucket for collaboration? What do I tell the junior devs to do? What do I (as the creator, owner, and admin of the repo ) have to do? What's the proper workflow that I should get used to?
2. What's the use of Pull Request? To my understanding, we can "Push" the local copy to the remote repo. And after that, we do a "Pull Request", and the whole team will check it. But what if I, as the admin, denied the push and pull request because it is broken or other reasons? What should I do?
3. And also in the pull request, there's an option to close branch after the pull request is merged (is it equal to accepting the pull request?). But when I click on it, the branch is still there on my local repo when I accepted the pull request. What is it for then?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Before saying STFW or RTFM, FYI, I have done so these past few months and still confused. And I've actually tried it myself but yeah, as you can see, I'm still very confused.

Comment: Your question is too long and would basically require a dissertation to completely answer.  Can you pare it down to ask about one git feature or one feature in BitBucket?

Comment: Ah yes. Maybe the questions are too vague. But IMHO the questions about pull request is the one that I needed answered. Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include only a single question.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should've. But IMHO it won't be necessary because I think I already have the answer I'm satisfied with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2) A pull request is a message that says "hey, I have some stuff to share, please pull from my repository." That's all there is to it. PR's used to be just e-mail messages. Websites like github and bitbucket made it into a "feature" with a button.

The concept of pull request assumes each of you has their own repo. Your repo on bitbucket might be the central repo of your workflow (voluntarily central, of course). If you have all write access to the central repo, there's no need to ask (make a pull request to) anybody to pull to it, because all of you can push to it on their own.

But it sounds like what you want to do is limit write access to the central bitbucket repo to yourself, allow other to read, and make them file pull request whenever they want to push to the central repo. You'd then review the pull request and either merge them or reject them.

Bitbucket may have some nice UI around it, but this is how it works in principle.

3) If you'd clone from it, the cloned repo shouldn't have the branch anymore and you now don't have to delete the branch on bitbucket, just in your local repo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So basically, pull request can be used as:

1. A notification for other devs that there's an update in the remote repo, if you have access to write.
2. Ask the admin to review, accept and merge the change if you don't have access to write.

Is it correct? For the first option, what if the other dev has pushed his work but the admin / lead (ie. me) reject it?

So the remote repo shouldn't have the branch if it has been closed from pull request but in the local repo it still exist? Got it.

Thanks again.

Comment: pull request == requesting that the admin should review, accept and merge a what's in my repo

Comment: If the other dev has write access to the central repo, he can push to it. If not, he can only push to his personal fork and then notify the admin via a pull request (that's probably the better way to do it). The dev can fix his work and issue another pull request, or he can completely abandon what he was working on. In the latter case, he can still keep the work on a personal branch (he should have started his work on a personal, i.e. "feature-branch" in the first place).

Comment: I recommend you take a look at git-flow for a good workflow with git. Github/bitbucket just wrap all the basic git stuff in a GUI and help you manage the massages between the people who work on your project.

Comment: I see. Ok, I think I got a better understanding now. BTW, a little OOT, I've experimented some more using a vm and a second faux BitBucket account. And I seem to get an idea about a good steps to use Bitbucket to collaborate. It's: code->(if there's an update) stash->pull update->apply stash->code again->commit->push->pull request->code->... Is this the correct way? Thanks.

Comment: Yup. I think that would be an acceptable workflow, although you could finish your commit first, thereby avoiding the stash part. If you constantly have to stash, it might mean the commits you're making are too big. Rebasing against upstream might be a better alternative to pulling from it (fetching it + merging it) for your devs, as it will result in a cleaner history (no merge commits). Ideally, those rebases should be a no-op (if people work on completely separate things).

Comment: Ok, I think I got the big picture. Thanks a lot. I'll check this as the answer.

Comment: Thanks it's kind of a lousy answer for not answering the first part, but I don't believe there's such a thing as "the proper way" for a workflow in general.